# What is the conjugation of the action verb in the [doing something is easy/hard] pattern?

Tags: conjugations

I can read [here](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/how-to-express-difficulty-and-possibility/) and [here](https://guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/easyhard) that 易い and 難い are added to the "stem of the verb", but I don't really see how the examples I can find then match this rule.

For sake of clarity, I provide here a definition of what a "stem" is from one Japanese Grammar book (Lampkin 2004, 11):

> The stem of a verb is the part that gives the general action or meaning; that is, "walk", "do", "sing", "hear", "be", etc.
> The stem of Yodan and Ichidan verbs is what is left after removing the last syllable of the Dictionary Form. For example, the stem of *hataraku* (work) is *hatara*-, the stem of taberu (eat) is *tabe*-, the stem of *iru* (be located) is *i*-, etc.

> Except for irregular verbs *kuru* (come) and *suru* (do), the stem of a verb never changes. The stems of *kuru* and *suru* change with each base, and it is this that gives them their irregular quality

From the following examples I could find on the internet, the rule is not applied, because otherwise we would have had 読やすい, 話やすい in the two first examples.

この本は読**み**やすい。

田中さんは話**し**やすい人（だ / です）。

この  質問は答**え**難い。

この  文法はおぼ**え**難い。

So what should be the form of the verb in the [doing something is easy/hard] pattern?

**References:**

Lampkin, R. (1995). *Japanese Verbs and Essentials of Grammar*, Passport Books

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the clarification of Leebo, I was able to reach this understanding:

(1) The 易い/難い adjectives should be attached to verbs that are conjugated in the Base 2 form (i.e. ending with the vowel -i) (This is the same Base to which is attached ます).

(2) Ichidan verbs do not have a Base 2 form, so 易い/難い should follow directly the stem of the verb, which corresponds to what we get when we remove the -る from the Dictionary form of the verb (or -ます when the verb is conjugated in -ます)

(3) So the two Ichidan verbs from the examples, when inside a [doing something is easy/hard] pattern should indeed be 覚え and 答え (覚える/覚えます, 答える/答えます), while the other two Yodan verbs should be 話し, 読み (Base 2 of 話す and 読む)

This answer is heavily based on (Lampkin 1995).